# Possible to supply two different configurations on the same physical network, so that they are selectable as 2 alternatives in NetworkManager?

Tags: routing, dhcp, networkmanager

Is it possible to supply two different network configurations (say, by two DHCP servers), so that they are selectable as 2 alternative wired connections in NetworkManager (GNU/Linux)?

The motivation for this question was explained at https://serverfault.com/questions/463885/two-different-dhcp-configurations-selectable-in-networkmanager.

If not DHCP, then: Are there other automatic network configuration discovery protocols that would allow this?

I mean that there should be 2 alternative connections discovered for the same physical wired network.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the purpose... The purpose of DHCP is to eliminate client-side configuration, right?

That said, you can create a second configuration with `Connect automatically` unchecked in NetworkManager, or `ONBOOT="no"` in the interface configuration file. (`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-<interface>`)  It becomes selectable in the `nm-applet` dropdown.

If you want non-administrators to be able to select the connection, choose `Available to all users`.

Comment: I do not want to enter the configuration on the client side. The wish is analoguous to what we can have with WiFI: there are several selectable wireless networks with their own configurations. Can we similarly supply two alternative configurations in the wired network? They would be two different routing possibilities (chosen by the owner of the connecting device): TOR and non-TOR (normal).

Comment: Ok, so see the second part explaining how to do it. I don't have to understand the purpose, but it will work regardless.